# Maven should stop if detect process exit code 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have built one solution for my application and in order to detect errors from frontend packages, I have done another application which throws an error and gives exit code 1 if something is wrong.

For that I used

```xml
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
```

to execute the program in maven.

The problem is that when my exit code is 1 (When I throw the error), the maven build don't stop.

Is there an option to stop the maven process if process failed?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant parts of your pom.xml? As is, the question is quite incomprehensible....

Comment: How do you detect errors from your frontend? Where are you running this app? Running as part of a test? Please add much more details...